# How to count number of records per month over a time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to run a query for a specified amount of time, say the last 5 months, and to be able to return how many records were created each month? Here's what my table looks like:

```
SELECT rID, dateOn FROM claims
```

Comment: You need a fitler and a `GROUP BY` with an aggregate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(rID) AS ClaimsPerMonth,
    MONTH(dateOn) AS inMonth,
    YEAR(dateOn) AS inYear FROM claims
WHERE dateOn >= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(dateOn), YEAR(dateOn)
ORDER BY inYear, inMonth
```

In this query the `WHERE dateOn >= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())` ensures that it's for the past 5 months, the `GROUP BY MONTH(dateOn)` then allows it to count per month.

And to appease the community, here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc98c/2/0) to prove it.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, no; have you?

Comment: I don't need to test it to see that there is no `MONTH(dateOn)` in your `SELECT` list

Comment: And this is why we need revision history within the first five minutes. Thanks for adding it to your `SELECT` list. Unfortunately, my down vote is locked unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, that's no problem. I missed the month counter when I first wrote the statement.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO What, you mean [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history)? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm quite okay with that and I like the one proposed by Mad Scientist.

Comment: wow... that's awesome! Am i right to assume that if i want to select the year, i just change the month info for year?

Comment: @Damien, yes you would change everything to work off the `YEAR`. It would be more than just one slight change, but it's a very minor permutation.

Comment: Just one last thing, i'm trying to order this by month, but i'm not having any luck, it seems to be ordering numerically, 1,8,9,10,11,12 instead of 8,9,10,11,12,1

Comment: @Damien, you would need to add the year first (e.g. `ORDER BY inYear, inMonth`) so you might want to add the year to the select list as well.

Comment: i tried order by inMonth but no luck... still the same results

Comment: @Damien, with my edit it will order it oldest to newest.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the other two answers, this will return all 5 months, even when the count is 0. It will also use an index on the onDate column, if a suitable one exists (the other two answers so far are non-sargeable).

```
DECLARE @nMonths INT = 5;

;WITH m(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@nMonths) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-number, 0) 
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
)
SELECT m.m, num_claims = COUNT(c.rID) 
  FROM m LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.claims AS c
  ON c.onDate >= m.m AND c.onDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.m)
  GROUP BY m.m
  ORDER BY m.m;
```

You also don't have to use a variable in the `TOP` clause, but this might make the code more reusable (e.g. you could pass the number of months as a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    count(rID) as Cnt,
    DatePart(Month, dateOn) as MonthNumber,
    Max(DateName(Month, dateOn)) as MonthName
FROM claims
WHERE dateOn >= DateAdd(Month, -5, getdate())
GROUP BY DatePart(Month, dateOn)
```